# VBA realtime filter Listbox through Cell Value

Tags: vba, excel, filter, listbox

I have a listbox in a worksheet and it is activating by clicking some specified cells. I would like to filter my listbox by writing on this cell. For example, if I write "asd" on that cell, the listbox should return lines which start with "asd" in realtime.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   On Error Resume Next
   If Target.Value <> "" Then
      With ListBox1
         For i = .ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If InStr(1, LCase(.List(i, 0)), LCase(Target.Value)) = 0 And _ 
            InStr(1, LCase(.List(i, 1)), LCase(Target.Value)) = 0 And _
            InStr(1, LCase(.List(i, 2)), LCase(Target.Value)) = 0 And _
            InStr(1, LCase(.List(i, 3)), LCase(Target.Value)) = 0 Then
               .RemoveItem i
            End If
          Next i
      End With
   End If
End Sub
```

I have that but it is not working.

Comment: what does "not working" actually mean? Give details about errors thrown and which line is throwing them

Comment: It is waiting for deactivating cell. I mean it works when you select another cell. But I would like to run it while you are writing. So, you can see suitable lines and select correct one.

Comment: AFAIK, It is not possible with `worksheet_change` event, because this event fires when all changes done, not when you deactivate cell (Yes, even if you hit Enter button - selection is changed, but you can write in formula bar, so cell is active and changed). You can build what you want if you add TextBox to your list, because such events textbox has.

Comment: May be capturing keystrokes could lead somewhere along the way you need, but it'd be hard times and I do think @CommonSense way is the real one to go

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this method - when the specific cell is changed then just remove all the items from the `ListBox` and populate with matching items from the source `Range`:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim strFilter As String
    Dim rngData As Range
    Dim lngCounter As Long

    ' check changed cell is our specific cell and exit if not
    If Intersect(Target, Sheet1.Range("B1")) Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'get reference to data range
    Set rngData = Sheet1.Range("A1:A12")

    'get value of changed cell
    strFilter = Target.Value

    'clear listbox and add matching items
    Sheet1.ListBox1.Clear
    For lngCounter = 1 To rngData.Rows.Count
        If Left(rngData.Cells(lngCounter, 1).Value, 1) = Target.Value Then
            Sheet1.ListBox1.AddItem rngData.Cells(lngCounter, 1).Value
        End If
    Next lngCounter

End Sub
```

For example:

[image]